# How to execute only all SQL files of which name starts with a two digit number in a folder and ignore all other SQL files?

Tags: batch-file, execute-sql-task

I have the following batch code which executes all SQL files of a folder.

```
for /r %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S localhost /d superDB /U sa /P topsecret -i"%%G"
pause
```

But now I want to execute only the files which start with a two digit number in name like:

```
01_file.sql
02_file.sql
05_file.sql
43_file.sql
```

But not files like:

```
optional_01_file.sql 
XYZ04_file.sql
```

Can someone tell me how to change the code to filter only files with a file name which starts with 2 digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Findstr's rudimentary RegEx capabilities are sufficient to match the files.
<s>Un</s>**Tested:**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\21\SO_51456661.cmd
@echo off
for /r %%G in (*.sql) do (
    Echo=%%~nG|Findstr "^[0-9][0-9]_" 2>&1>Nul && (
        echo sqlcmd /S localhost /d superDB /U sa /P topsecret -i"%%G"
    )
)
```

In a folder with these files

```
> dir /B *.sql
01_file.sql
0815_file.sql
55_file.sql
abc0855_file.sql
```

I get these commands (only echoed for demonstration)

```
> SO_51456661.cmd
sqlcmd /S localhost /d superDB /U sa /P topsecret -i"Q:\Test\2018\07\21\01_file.sql"
sqlcmd /S localhost /d superDB /U sa /P topsecret -i"Q:\Test\2018\07\21\55_file.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following batch file for this task:

```
@for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "%~dp0??_*.sql" /A-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /R "[0123456789][0123456789]"') do @sqlcmd.exe /S localhost /d superDB /U sa /P topsecret -i"%~dp0%%G"
```

This batch file expects that the *.sql files starting with `[0-9][0-9]_` are stored in same directory as the batch file and the current directory on running the batch file can be any directory which is useful on running this batch file as scheduled task on which the **Start in** option of scheduled task is not set.

To process the *.sql files in current directory instead of directory of the batch file just remove both occurrences of `%~dp0` which expands to drive and path of the batch file. The expanded batch file path string always ends with a backslash.

Both `%~dp0` can be replaced also by any other folder path ending with a backlash.

The command **FOR** with the used options runs in a separate command process started with `cmd /C` in background the command line

```
dir "C:\Batch File Path\??_*.sql" /A-D-H /B /ON 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /B /R /C:[0123456789][0123456789]
```

The command **DIR** searches for

- just non hidden files because of `/A-D-H` (attribute NOT directory and NOT hidden)
- in directory of the batch file
- for files matching the wildcard pattern `??_*.sql`
- and outputs just file name + file extension to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) because of `/B` (bare format)
- order alphabetically by name because of `/ON`.

**DIR** is an internal command of `cmd.exe` already running for processing this batch file.

An error message output by **DIR** on not finding any file name matching the criteria written to handle **STDERR** (standard error) is redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it.

The output of **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** is redirected with `|` to handle **STDIN** (standard input) of next command **FINDSTR** being an external command which means a console executable available by default in Windows system directory.

**FINDSTR** searches for lines read from **STDIN** which

- begin because of `/B`
- with a string matching `[0123456789][0123456789]`
- which is interpreted as regular expression search string because of using explicitly `/R`.

See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/) for the reason using `[0123456789][0123456789]` instead of `[0-9][0-9]` because of `[0-9]` matches also the three characters `¹²³` on being encoded with code page Windows-1252.

**FINDSTR** outputs all lines (= file names) matching the regular expression applied to only the first two characters to handle **STDOUT** of background command process.

**FOR** captures those file names and process them line by line. `delims=` defines an empty list for string splitting to assign always full name of file to loop variable `G` even if the *.sql file name contains one or more spaces.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `|` and `2>nul`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background.

Best would be to specify also `sqlcmd.exe` with full path on running this batch file as scheduled task for making the batch file independent on environment variable `PATH` of the environment (account) used for running the scheduled task.

It is a bit unclear if just *.sql files starting with two digits and an underscore in a folder or recursively in a folder and all its subfolders should be executed with `sqlcmd`.

Here is a variant of above batch file command line for running all *.sql starting with `[0-9][0-9]_` in entire folder tree starting with folder containing the batch file:

```
@for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "%~dp0??_*.sql" /A-D-H /B /ON /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"\\[0123456789][0123456789]_[^\\]*$"') do @sqlcmd.exe /S localhost /d superDB /U sa /P topsecret -i"%%G"
```

The command **DIR** is used additionally with option `/S` which results in searching also in subdirectories for files matching the wildcard pattern `??_*.sql`.

The output by **DIR** changes with `/S` as the file names are output now with complete file path.

For that reason **FINDSTR** is without `/B` and the regular expression is modified to `\\[0123456789][0123456789]_[^\\]*$` to get just output the *.sql files starting with two digits in file name independent on file path.

The command `sqlcmd` is called just with `%%G` as the loop variable holds the full qualified file name (= file path + file name + file extension) of the current SQL file to use.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `sqlcmd -?`

Answer (score 0):

I would filter the files by name using [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
    dir /S /B /A:-D "*.sql" ^| ^
        findstr /I /R /C:"\\[0123456789][0123456789]_[^\\]*\.sql$"
') do (
    sqlcmd /S localhost /d superDB /U sa /P topsecret -i"%%G"
)
pause
```